# Android configuration devices in Eclipse

Tags: android, configuration, screen, device

I am looking for a list of configurations to import on my Eclipse because in my Eclipse I have the screen size 4" and 4.7" but for example I want the screen 4.3" and the same density of HTC EVO 3D.

Where can I find a list with these information?

I looked on google but I didn't find anything.

Comment: By density do you mean the resolution of the device?

Comment: I mean all informations to setup the display as HTC EvO 3d, htc desire , etc...